# Javascript Push array to array with unique key

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have object with array like that:

```
const result = {
    key1: [],
    key2: [],
    key3: [],
    key4: []
};
```

And I want to push to one of the "key" something like that:

```
result.key1.push({key11: []})
result.key1.push({key12: []})
result.key1.push({key13: []})
```

But I need the result looks like that:

```
{
    key1: [
        key11: [],
        key12: [],
        key13: []
    ],
    key2: [],
    key3: [],
    key4: []
}
```

I tried almost everything did I miss something?

Comment: Arrays have keys that are positive integers, `key11` is a object property

Comment: Rephrasing, Arrays can only have keys that are positive integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up objects and arrays. Arrays have items in order, from 0 to length - 1, while objects have named keys. It seems that you're looking for having named keys, so you need to create an object instead.

```
const result = {
    key1: {},
    key2: {},
    key3: {},
    key4: {},
};
```

Now simply assign items.

```
result.key1.key11 = []
result.key1.key12 = []
result.key1.key13 = []
```